# Bootstrap 3: Issue with min-height: 100%

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, height, sections

So I'm working on a layout ([see here](http://www.reversl.net/test/)) in Bootstrap that splits a one page website into different content sections. I'd like each section to fill the screen beneath the navbar. I'm also using Bootstraps fixed navbar `navbar-fixed-top`. I've followed Bootstrap's recommendation of adding a 50px padding to the top of `<body>`

```
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
```

which is supposed to account for portions of each section that are hidden beneath the fixed navbar.

The problem I'm having is that on page-load everything works fine (each section fills the screen) However, if I click any menu item in the navigation - the corresponding `<section id>` defaults back to hiding a portion of the section beneath the navbar. I end up with each section ending roughly 50px from the bottom of the viewport.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add `padding-top:50px` to each section instead of to the `body`

The problem is related to the fact you are using the `id` of each section as the anchor reference, so it is being pushed to the top of the body- an alternative would be to give each section `position:relative` then add to each an anchor element with `position:absolute;top:-50px;` and use these for navigation.

Comment: adding a padding-top:50px to each section limits my control of content within each section. Right now I'd like content (a few lines of text) to appear center of each section & so I'm adding a padding-top: 100px to <section>. Your alternative solution of absolute positioning will work as a fall-back but I'd prefer a solution that requires less code if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS

```
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
    webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: so while this causes the content box to fill the entire screen it unfortunately adds a little more than 100%. i.e. I have to scroll a little past the fold to see the next section. Ideally, each section would just fill the screen and no more - if that makes sense

Comment: i have changed my answer if you apply content box on body then it dose exactly what you want.

Comment: Aaahhh so close. I've applied your solution and now each section does fill the screen, however each section also fills behind the navbar. Not a big problem by the way - I was just curious to see if there was a simple way around this. Thanks